# Limits of inverse trigonometric fucnctions

Tags: limits, inverse-function

I was solving for $x$ if

> $$\lim_{n \rightarrow\infty}(\sin^{-1}(x))^n = 0$$

and got the answer as $x$ is all values except $0$ and $\{\pi/2+n\pi\}$ for all integers $n$. Am I right ?

Comment: It is arcsin function

Comment: You would almost be correct if the question read $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{(\sin x)^n} = 0$ (in this case $x=0$ works as well). However, this is $\sin^{-1}$, not $\sin$.

Answer (score 3):

One has that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|x|^n=\begin{cases}0, \quad \text{if } |x|<1 \\ 1,   \quad \text{if }|x|=1 \\ +\infty,  \quad \text{if } |x|>1\end{cases},$$
And in particular the first holds without absolute value.

Thus you need to find the inverse image  of $(-1,1)$ under arcsin, i.e.
$$\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid |\arcsin(x)|<1\}\iff \{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid |x|<\sin(1)\}=(-\sin(1),\sin(1))$$

Comment: If arcsin(x) < 1, how x < sin (1). Should the value of x not be in radians like what I have obtained ? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I got it. Thanks.